# Multiple Booting

Tags: dual-boot

I have Dell Inspiron shipped with Win 10 Home Edition and MS Office. 1 TB of HDD with partition of C: 416 GB; E and F each having 249 GB. I want to Boot Ubuntu LTS, Kali Linux, Arch Linux and Fedora. Later on maybe Gentoo and Slackware also.

1. Will this Multiple booting cause any problem to Win 10 and purchased applications from MS Store?
2. How do I partition 249 GB of F Drive for each of these OS? (when I shrink Volume in Disk Management Utility, it all goes into one Unallocated space. Or shall I Make New Volumes to Boot Different OS)

Any recommendation on multiple Booting will be of great help. Consider Me taking 1st Dive into Ocean of Linux

Comment: Linux only boots from LInux formatted partitions which you cannot create from Windows tools. I use 30GB and have multiple Ubuntu installs, but large ext4 partition for my data to make it usable in all installs. Back with XP I had two data partitions, one NTFS and one LInux format. Not sure about other installs, they may want other formats as default. I think Fedora wants LVM which is better for entire drive, so you may just want a standard partition. Start with one install and first learn dual booting. If new system, be sure all installs are UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult to install so many operating systems on just one or two drives. I would suggest to use VMs in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think multi booting will mess with Win10 or purchased applications normally.

Since you have unallocated space, you can install a distro right on the unallocated space, as most linux distros will have options to help with creating a new volume and partitioning. I don't think you need to create a new volume first on windows. I know this to be true for all debian based operating systems.

Comment: If someone has had an experience where dual booting will mess with windows 10 purchased apps, could you leave a comment? I will then correct my response.